# Bind value of blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

```
<EditForm Model="cust" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="@(this.Id == null? this.idNuM :cust._nunuy)" class="form-control"></InputNumber>
</EditForm>
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
>
> The type arguments for method 'RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(object, Action, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

**I tried it:**

```
<EditForm Model="cust" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="@(this.Id == null? (ulong)this.idNuM : (long)cust._nunuy)" class="form-control"></InputNumber>
</EditForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<EditForm Model="cust" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="@(() =>this.Id == null? this.idNuM :cust._nunuy)" class="form-control"></InputNumber>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: No, it's the same Error..